# Get (x,y) touch coordinates in Android spinner elements

Tags: android, touch, spinner, coordinates, items

does anyone know how to get the x,y coordinates of a touch on a spinner item?

I'm able to get all the other coordinates on each element but for some reason I'm not able to get the ones of the spinner elements when popped out.

I can get the (x,y) coordinates while I touch the spinner but not the coordinates of its items when I select one.

I'm overriding the Android **dispatchTouchEvent()** function in this way, where the **manageTouch()** is my function to get the coordinates and write them to a .txt file.

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    manageTouch(event);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
View view = spinner.getChildAt(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());

    int[] posXY = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(posXY);

    int x = posXY[0];
    int y = posXY[1];
```

you can call this on spinner item selection event .

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I think this is not completely good for my problem. getLocationOnScreen return the coordinates of the item, not the coordinates of the touch on that item: later I should compute a fake touch using the item's coordinates.
**I was looking for a better solution to get all the touch coordinates on the elements that android pops out (alert, spinner items, etc)**
Thanks anyway =)